# Are colons required after labels in ABI compliant ARM

Tags: arm, abi

I have seen examples of labels in ARM with and without colons following the symbol name. Is the colon required?

I was under the impression that colons are required, but an example from ARM's site is missing them: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0100a/armasm_ceghjdfb.htm

Comment: assembly language is defined by the assembler not the target.  the language is not limited to the mnemonics that represent instructions, you dont often get too much of a variation there, but sometimes you do.  where the bigger differences are are the rest of the language, the labels, directives, macros, etc.  .test vs SECTION TEXT with or without a colon on labels, what character marks a comment, how to represent hex and decimal numbers, etc.

Comment: arm the company has had at least three generations of tools that I know of that they sell and support, but at the same time at least when I was paying attention they had at least one person involved in gnu to keep that toolchain on track.  and arm assembler I have seen doesnt appear to use colons on labels where gnu assembler does.

Comment: doesnt matter what target, if you want to write assembly language you have to use the language that matches the tool you are using to read it.

Comment: the abi is the calling convention not a language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presence or absence of a colon after a label is a matter of assembler syntax and does not get included in the object file and therefore not an ABI concern. [GNU assembler requires a trailing colon](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Labels.html#Labels), some other assemblers prohibit a trailing colon.

The preceding underscores required by some ABIs are not treated specially by assemblers and are required to be compatible with a C compiler for those ABIs.